# CSS float feature is not working for everyone

Tags: css, css-float

I have a blog and am using the CSS float feature for highlighted text in boxes within my article. So, if there is an important sentence or two in my article, I showcase that within a text box using float.

For many of my readers, this displays correctly. But some of them say that the text that is supposed to be inside a highlight box appears as inline text, and so they complain that I have repetitions in the article.

Why is this happening? I thought that in html, if the browser does not understand something, it is supposed to ignore it. So, in this case, I would have thought that if their browser did not support CSS, etc., then it should have simply ignored the text in the highlight boxes, not reproduced them as plain text.

This is the CSS code I am using:

```
#boxedquote {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0.5em 0em 0.5em 2em;
    padding: 0.1em 1em 0.1em 1em;
    border: 4px solid;
    border-color: Gold;
    border-radius: 10 px;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#boxedHighlights {
    color: #556B2F;
}
```

This is an example of how it is used:

```
                <div id="boxedquote">
                    <div id="boxedHighlights">
                        <p>
                            The possibility of a romance of a Muslim &ldquo;villain&rdquo; with a Hindu queen being depicted on screen, even as a fantasy, as has been rumoured, infuriates Hindu right-wing groups.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my blog page:

http://www.leftbrainwave.com/2017/11/why-indian-civilization-should-be.html

Comment: First of all, you are right that if a browser doesn't recognise something, it ignores it. It might ignore CSS, tags, attributes etc. But never text! Secondly, the floating mechanism is very, very old, so you'd be hard pressed to find a browser now that doesn't support it at all. I think something else is going on. Is there a pattern to the hardware or software that your complaining users are using?

Comment: The page does contain a lot of errors, by the way. I looks like you have pasted several complete HTML documents after one another into one, can that be right? I don't know if that can cause the problems, but it wouldn't hurt to run your page through a validator and correct the worst errors.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by errors. I use blogger, and I create my post using bluefish as an html editor, and then I paste the html into blogger. Blogger has a whole bunch of other things that I don't know about.

What is a validator and where do I get one?

Comment: The [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) for instance. It reports errors such as multiple <body> start tags, duplicate IDs, tags in locations where they don't belong etc. 71 errors and 33 warnings in all. And different browsers have different error handling routines, so it's not strange that it looks differently for different people.

Comment: Thanks. Will go through these errors.